# How to iterate a services, methods, and method arguments within a protoc python plugin?

Tags: python, protoc

The aim is to generate helper methods that will aid to call a GRPC service dynamically. The requirement is to take in keyword arguments and validate the name and type against the expected types within the GRPC service method argument.

This is the code I have been attempting to use, but I haven't been able to find the definition of messages anywhere. The method has a input and output type, but no definition as far as I can see.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import sys
import chevron

from google.protobuf.compiler import plugin_pb2 as plugin
from google.protobuf.descriptor import FieldDescriptor, Descriptor
from google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2 import FileDescriptorProto


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
)


def process_file(
    proto_file: FileDescriptorProto,
    response: plugin.CodeGeneratorResponse,
    bytes: bytes,
) -> None:
    logger.info(f"Processing proto_file: {proto_file.name}")

    content = ""

    methods = []

    # proto_file.ParseFromString

    for service in proto_file.service:

        for method in service.method:
            field_names: list[str] = []
            fields: list[tuple[FieldDescriptor, str]] = method.ListFields()

            # for a method it has three fields. Method, Input type,
            # and output type.

            # The field descriptor for the input and output types have
            # a containing_type. The fields on the containing type has
            # a name and type. The name is a string, but the type is
            # is number. The number corresponds to the static attributes
            # on the FieldDescriptor class. CPPTYPE_STRING = 9, etc.

            [request_fields, name] = fields[1]
            containing_type: Descriptor = request_fields.containing_type
            request_fields.

            request_parameters = []
            for field in containing_type.fields:
                request_parameters.append(
                    {'name': field.name, 'type': field.type}
                )

            methods.append({
                'service_name': service.name,
                'method_name': method.name,
                'input_type': method.input_type,
                'output_type': method.output_type,
                'descriptor_name': method.DESCRIPTOR.name,
                'field_names': field_names,
                'request_parameters': request_parameters,
            })

    with open('templates/marshaller.mustache', 'r') as f:
        content = chevron.render(f, {
            'methods': methods,
            'dependencies': proto_file.dependency,
        })

        file = response.file.add()
        file.name = f"{service.name}Marshaller.py"
        file.content = content


def process(
    request: plugin.CodeGeneratorRequest,
    response: plugin.CodeGeneratorResponse,
    bytes: bytes,
) -> None:
    for proto_file in request.proto_file:
        process_file(proto_file, response, bytes)


def main() -> None:
    # Load the request from stdin
    bytes = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
    request = plugin.CodeGeneratorRequest.FromString(bytes)

    # Create a response
    response = plugin.CodeGeneratorResponse()

    process(request, response, bytes)

    # Serialize response and write to stdout
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(response.SerializeToString())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

template

```
{{#methods}}
def {{service_name}}_{{method_name}}(*args, **kwargs):
    assert len(args) == 0, 'positional arguments are not supported'
    # input type = {{input_type}}
    # output type = {{output_type}}

    # {{descriptor_name}}
    {{#field_names}}
        # field name = {{.}}
    {{/field_names}}

    # request parameters
    {{#request_parameters}}
    # name = {{name}}
    # type = {{type}}

    {{/request_parameters}}

{{/methods}}
# dependencies 
{{#dependencies}}
# dependency = {{.}}
{{/dependencies}}
```